# How do I change which desktop my files are saved to with multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitors and was wondering if there was a way to make it so that I would be asked which desktop to save my files to.

Comment: Well, to begin with, it is only one desktop. I suspect what you are asking is if there is a way to have it ask what location on the desktop it should display the icon at. If that is the case I suspect that it isn't possible but I don't know that definitively.

Comment: I do not think this is possible as your "default" monitor will be the location to place these icons.
 

What we perceive as the desktop is just a folder with links and documents. You can see this by going to Desktop in file explorer. 

The registry controls the location of desktop icons at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop. 
The problem may then be how to change the default in registry but keep your default monitor the same.